Getting different query results from Firebase
When I query firebase using the auto-generated code from Flutterflow, I get one record.
When I query with my own code running on Pipedream using the Firebase SDK, I get two records.
When I look directly at the firebase console, there should only be two records that match the query.
I cannot figure out the issue with the Flutterflow query:
child: FutureBuilder<List<CompactionsRecord>>(
  future: queryCompactionsRecordOnce(
    queryBuilder: (compactionsRecord) => compactionsRecord
        .where(
          'userCreated',
          isEqualTo: currentUserReference,
        )
        .orderBy('createDateTime', descending: true),
    limit: 20,
  ),

This is my query:
import { initializeApp, cert, getApps } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    firebase_admin_sdk: {
      type: "app",
      app: "firebase_admin_sdk",
    }
  },
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    try {
      if (!getApps().length) {
        const firebaseConfig = {
          credential: cert({
            projectId: this.firebase_admin_sdk.$auth.projectId,
            clientEmail: this.firebase_admin_sdk.$auth.clientEmail,
            privateKey: this.firebase_admin_sdk.$auth.privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
          }),
          databaseURL: this.firebase_admin_sdk.$auth.customDatabaseUrl,
        };

        initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      }

      const db = getFirestore();

      // Assuming 'userId' is a string with the user's ID
      const userId = steps.trigger.event.body.userId;
      console.log(userId);    

      // Assuming 'users' is a collection where user documents are stored
      const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);
      console.log(userRef);

      const limitString = steps.trigger.event.body.limit;
      const limitInt = parseInt(limitString, 10); // Convert string to integer
      const playlistId = steps.trigger.event.body.playlistId;

      console.log(limitInt);
      console.log(playlistId);

      let query = db.collection('compactions')
               .where('userCreated', '==', userRef)
               .orderBy('createDateTime', 'desc');

      if (playlistId !== "") {
        query = query.where('playlistId', '==', playlistId);
      }

      const querySnapshot = await query.limit(limitInt).get();

      const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                                                ...doc.data(),
                                                docRef: doc.ref.path // Include the document reference path
                                              }));

      return documents;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching documents:", error);
      // Map Firebase error to HTTP status code as needed
      let statusCode = 500; // Default to internal server error
      if (error.code === 'permission-denied') {
        statusCode = 403; // Forbidden
      }
      // Add more error mappings as needed

      return { error: "Failed to fetch documents", details: error.toString(), statusCode };
    }
  },
});

Where can the problem with the Flutterflow be?
I have been working on this problem for over two weeks and I have tried to change the indexes, I manually changed all the records to simplify the problem by having the EQUALITY filter value be just two values.
I have tried different versions of the auto-gen query and I still have the same issue.
